# Spring - Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm very new to JAVA web applications so keep this in mind. I've taken on a very big project, it's daunting. I finally got the Maven dependancies fixed and am now getting my first errors when running on Tomcat.

What does this error mean please? How does one fix go about fixing it?

What does Autowired do?

What does Hibernate Session Factory do? Could a bad jdbc.properties file settings screw everything up?

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'billfoldApplicationDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.AbstractBaseDao.init(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl] for bean with name 'itemConfigFactoryImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/Stu/Development/EclipseFresh/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/crazyowls-demo-web/WEB-INF/lib/crazyowls-game-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ctx-grazyowl-game.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void eu.digient.billfold.support.dao.AbstractBaseDao.init(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl] for bean with name 'itemConfigFactoryImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/Stu/Development/EclipseFresh/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/crazyowls-demo-web/WEB-INF/lib/crazyowls-game-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ctx-grazyowl-game.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:604)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
... 22 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl] for bean with name 'itemConfigFactoryImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/Stu/Development/EclipseFresh/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/crazyowls-demo-web/WEB-INF/lib/crazyowls-game-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ctx-grazyowl-game.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1350)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
... 24 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1273)
... 33 more
```

Spring Config for module containing eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="goshgameProperties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<util:properties id="goshgameProperties" location="classpath:goshgame.properties" />

<bean id="itemConfigFactoryImpl" class="eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl">
    <property name="properties" ref="goshgameProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Does `ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl` mean anything to you?  Are you missing a jar file on your classpath?  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Explaining what Autowire and Hibernate Session Factory are is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow. These concepts are documented already and you should be reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great answer of what is and do @Autowired - [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)
I'll suggest you to use @Inject instead of @Autowired, because @Autowired is Spring-specific annotation. More could be found here - [Inject and Resource and Autowired annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450902/inject-and-resource-and-autowired-annotations)
I've asked similar question about properties and creating bean with @autowired: [Connection to database with JdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491434/connection-to-database-with-jdbctemplate) Maybe the problem with beans is with your properties (.properties or .xml) file.

Yes, spring obviously doesn't found the class you are searching for. You could try to search it in your target directory.

Comment: The class is there, maybe it's the lack of spring config settings. All those links were helpful thanks. JAVA terminology wording is killing me but I'm starting to attach concepts to JAVA terminology now which is the hard bit. So does @Inject bypass the errors?

Comment: No, it's pretty same like @Autowired, but since it is java configuration approach makes your application more flexible and not depending only to Spring. To try to fix it, you could check your spring config.xml file. There should be something like:    ` <beans>
    <bean name="transferService" class="com.acme.TransferServiceImpl"/>
</beans>` . Further information could be found here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: Yes I it's in the config. I Edited the Spring config into the question above, it  seems to be ok. I'll look into the .properties settings now.

Comment: Ok I think it was the jdbc.properties setup was wrong and failing to connect the HibernateDAO (no idea what that means yet). I believe from the error it was being inherited, though I can't be sure as I didn't write the code. Your help was much appreciated, sometimes you just need a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

It says ClassNotFoundException: eu.digient.billfold.goshgame.game.level.ItemConfigFactoryImpl

Check if this class is present and added in spring config file

Comment: Hi, I have checked the config and it seems ok? What do you think, I've added it to my question.

Comment: The thing is that after reading your config, it will try to initialize this class. Check that this class exist in your classpath. Do ctrl+Shift+T, write the name of the class. Check the package and classname is correct.