# JdbcTemplate not working with autowiring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am creating a REST application using Springboot. After doing some research I added JdbcTemplate to it rather than working directly with Jdbc and resultsets. I have the following configuration in `application.properties`.

```
server.context-path=/foo
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://url
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

My REST controller has the following code

```
@RestController
public class LosController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public String Bar(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        response = gson.toJson(bar.getData());
        return response;
    }
```

and in this object, I have

```
public class Bar {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<BarObject> getData(){
        String selectSql = "SELECT * FROM BAR";
        System.out.println(selectSql);
        System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().toString());

        List<BarObject> barObjs = jdbcTemplate.query(selectSql, new BarMapper());       

        return barObjs;
    }
}
```

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697190/spring-boot-autoconfiguration-with-jdbc-template-autowiring-datasource-issue) and configured everything as mentioned. I am able to see the `System.out.println(selectSql`) working. But at the next line, I am getting a `null pointer exception`. So the JdbcTemplate object isn't getting the data is what I feel. How can I get this working? I am trying to not use any xml configurations, which is the reason why I went for a properties file.

Answer (score 2):

`Bar` is not a spring bean.

To get it working, you can annotate `Bar` with `@Component` and autowire it in `LosController` rather than creating with `new`.

```
@RestController
public class LosController {

    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public String Bar(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        response = gson.toJson(bar.getData());
        return response;
    }
}

@Component
public class Bar {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public List<BarObject> getData(){
        String selectSql = "SELECT * FROM BAR";
        System.out.println(selectSql);
        System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().toString());

        List<BarObject> barObjs = jdbcTemplate.query(selectSql, new BarMapper());       

        return barObjs;
    }
}
```

Comment: that give me another error `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency`. The full error message is bigger but from what I understand, it is not able to create the JdbcTemplate bean

Comment: check that the package where the implementation is located in is scanned (check your <context:component-scan base-package= -value).

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao implementation of what? My application class is just annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: sorry I don't see it..maybe spring doesn't know which bean inject...put @qualifier("jdbcTemplate") just for test..