# Springboot + MySQL + Driver Class Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8, threadpool

I'm doing a simple spring boot project with a thread pool and MySQL in order to connect to MySQL whenever I'm adding spring-boot-starter-jdbc I'm getting below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.s
```

**Update 1:**

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: please share your pom.xml you might be missing the mysql jdbc driver dependency

Comment: Please check updated post

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are missing mysql-connector dependency,
Add these to your pom.

Maven:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

or gradle:

```
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:*"
```

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget to add dependency to MySQL (Spring Boot is using H2 database by default), you should add next lines to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added mysql-connector-java

Answer (score 0):

First include this in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Second, clean install the maven project.
If you are using eclipse check your JDK version and maven (Sometime jre is used instead of jdk, so, though in console everything looks fine but acutally the jar is not downloaded)
in short .m2 repo should have this jar file when maven build is done.

Comment: at compile not I'm not getting error, I have used JdbcTemplate

Comment: sure , give me the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36079859/5086633 useful links .....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821521/configure-datasource-programmatically-in-spring-boot... also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042426/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-datasource-defined-in-class-path-r

Answer (score 0):

Scope "runtime" is good for unit test and container as tomcat etc. when container provide jdbc driver. When run standalone apps (spring-boot) you should remove it or set to "compile".

Comment: 'mvn dependency:tree'

Comment: I haven't install MAVEN locally

Comment: You can execute this goal in ide. Which one you use?

Comment: I'm using eclipse

Comment: I can see all required Jars are there